# Techniques for condensing code

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I understand it, python is specifically designed to force people to use indentation but is it possible to break this rule.  As an example:

```
y=[1,2,3]

print('ListY:')
    for x in y:
        print(x)
```

Now, I can condense the last two lines as such:

```
for x in y:print(x)
```

but I cannot do:

```
print('ListY');for x in y:print(x)
```

But is there a way you can?

Comment: `for x in ['ListY:'] + y: print(x)`. BTW, what is the point of doing this?

Comment: python is specifically designed to force people to write code that other people can read. if you want the shortest number of lines, try perl instead.

Comment: If your interest is, say, academic, you can try viewing answers on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. If you're attempting to perform those tricks on production code, you should stop immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I should say that I agree that such tricks may be of some use. Not too often, though. A good example is code in doctests. It is usually clear enough to be readable even when compacted, and making it compact often makes less problems than making it "as readable as possible". However, for regular code joining lines is usually not a good practice. When you are not able to create a breakpoint inside `if` or `for` statement, it's usually a bigger problem than an extra line. Also the coverage tools give more information in case you do not practice such tricks.

However, answering your question, it seems there is no way to do what you want. There are many limitations in using `;`. [Compound statements](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) can not be used with `;`. Usually these limitations are reasonable, but sometimes I also regret they are so strict.

**UPD:** But if you are very focused on making it a one-liner, there is a lot of tricks. For example, generators and list comprehensions (instead of `for`), `reduce()` and so on, and in Python 3 even `print()` can be used inside them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entering in why you would ever want to do that on Python, but no, you can't do that.

There are two types of statements in Python: [simple statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) that span one line and [compund statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) that span several lines. You can put several simple statements into one line, separating them by semicolons, but you can't put a compound statement after a simple statement.

Namely (straight from the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html)):

```
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

Comment: much appreciated for the description

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(g,xs):
    for x in xs:
        g(x)

print('ListY');f(print,[1,2,3])
```

As the other answers say...

You could (if you really wanted) do something like this although you wouldn´t.

Often taking a "functional" approach can shorten code (or at least allows for cleaner re-use of code) Have a look at pythons ´partial´function and others in the [functools library](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functools.html)